# Using keycloak api for a public client

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

Working on a project where there is a frontend (React) and a backend (Java/Quarkus). Keycloak is used as the auth tool. It is configured with a realm that has a public client on it. This allows the user to login via the browser and then make api requests to the backend with a bearer token attached to the request.

Running into a problem where we want to add users to our application. This means we also need to add them to keycloak. Doing this programatically, this is in its own mini module and it uses the `keycloak-admin-client` library.

I initiate the instance with

```
instance = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
    .serverUrl(props.getProperty(PropertyConstants.SERVER_URL))
    .realm(props.getProperty(PropertyConstants.REALM))
    .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
    .clientId(props.getProperty(PropertyConstants.CLIENT_ID))
    .username(props.getProperty(PropertyConstants.USERNAME))
    .password(props.getProperty(PropertyConstants.PASSWORD))
    .build();

    realmResource = instance.realm(props.getProperty(PropertyConstants.REALM));
    usersResource = realmResource.users();

    UserRepresentation user = createUserRep();
    Response response = usersResource.create(user);
```

The stacktrace is;

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: javax.ws.rs.core.Form$1
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:136)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.access$000(VertxRequestHandler.java:40)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:97)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.CleanableExecutor$CleaningRunnable.run(CleanableExecutor.java:231)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: javax.ws.rs.core.Form$1
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.invoke(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:287)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:488)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:149)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:112)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy89.grantToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.grantToken(TokenManager.java:90)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessToken(TokenManager.java:70)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.getAccessTokenString(TokenManager.java:65)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.BearerAuthFilter.filter(BearerAuthFilter.java:52)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.filterRequest(ClientInvocation.java:683)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:485)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:149)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:112)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.demservices.KeycloakWrapper.addUser(KeycloakWrapper.java:56)
    at com.demservices.services.UserService.addUser(UserService.java:27)
    at com.demservices.services.UserService_Subclass.addUser$$superaccessor2(UserService_Subclass.zig:492)
    at com.demservices.services.UserService_Subclass$$function$$2.apply(UserService_Subclass$$function$$2.zig:33)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:127)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:100)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:32)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:53)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:26)
    at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired_Bean.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired_Bean.zig:340)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at com.demservices.services.UserService_Subclass.addUser(UserService_Subclass.zig:440)
    at com.demservices.services.UserService_ClientProxy.addUser(UserService_ClientProxy.zig:251)
    at com.demservices.controllers.UserController.createNewUser(UserController.java:35)
    at com.demservices.controllers.UserController_Subclass.createNewUser$$superaccessor1(UserController_Subclass.zig:234)
    at com.demservices.controllers.UserController_Subclass$$function$$1.apply(UserController_Subclass$$function$$1.zig:33)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.interceptor.AbstractMethodValidationInterceptor.validateMethodInvocation(AbstractMethodValidationInterceptor.java:69)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.jaxrs.JaxrsEndPointValidationInterceptor.validateMethodInvocation(JaxrsEndPointValidationInterceptor.java:35)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.validator.runtime.jaxrs.JaxrsEndPointValidationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(JaxrsEndPointValidationInterceptor_Bean.zig:392)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at com.demservices.controllers.UserController_Subclass.createNewUser(UserController_Subclass.zig:191)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:643)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:507)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:457)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:459)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:419)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:393)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:68)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: javax.ws.rs.core.Form$1
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ClientWriterInterceptorContext.throwWriterNotFoundException(ClientWriterInterceptorContext.java:50)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.getWriter(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:302)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.syncProceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:240)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:224)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.writeRequestBody(ClientInvocation.java:440)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.writeRequestBodyToOutputStream(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:589)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.buildEntity(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:548)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.loadHttpMethod(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:455)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.invoke(ManualClosingApacheHttpClient43Engine.java:265)
    ... 77 more
```

I see in any example that a `clientSecret` is required but that is for confidential clients. I don't want this, I need the client to be public.

How can I have a public client while also being able to make API calls to it?

Comment: exception root problem: `content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded`! (some http request header...(i assume the one to `userResource.createUser(usr)`), please show: userResource and createUserResp!

Comment: So trying userResource.toString() gives me - RESTEASY004635: Resteasy Client Proxy for : org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.UsersResource

Comment: There is no response, it just throws the error

Comment: Found the solution here - https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/13667#issuecomment-750871898